# How to generate OTP in Power apps(OTP should appear in Phone Number) || instead of Phone number I tried using Email ID

Tags: sql, powerapps

I want to generate OTP of 4digits and One Time Password should come in registered Phone number.

I tried using 3rd party app but couldn't achieve this.
My data source is SQL.
Can't really able to do so, as I am unable to find the custom connector in power apps( I tried the steps generated on ChatGPT)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please show your effort instead of just mention i have tried with.... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do this by self as I couldn't able to get any source of help. So I got to know that If we want to send the OTP through the Phone number then for that we need to get a paid service(might be I'm not correct in this), instead of that I tried to send the OTP through Email Id.

Here are the steps if you want to achieve this -

step 1-
Create a Button in which you want to generate the OTP. And I gave the following codes -

Reset(TextInput2_1);            // resetting the text input which user will use for entering the OTP

Set(Votp,Right(Rand(),5));     // I set a variable and generating the random number and taking only 5 digits using right()

Gmail.SendEmail(DataCardValue6.Text,{Subject:"Put your subject name here", Body:"How you want your body should be put here "&Votp});     // this is the Email that you want to generate

Navigate(OTPScrn)          // Navigating to another screen

Step -2
after that entering the OTP need to add another button for checking the Otp is correct or not then log in.
In the Log in button I have added -
If(Votp = TextInput2_1.Text, Navigate(HomePage), Notify("Invalid OTP", NotificationType.Error));

Note- I've created two Screen in one only Email ID and Generate OTP button and in the 2nd Screen Otp input and log in button. I tried tried to insert the pictures as well but I'm new here so I couldn't able to it is asking some reputation.

Hope you guys understand, If further any issue you're facing let me know here. Thank You.